# How to automate the Mobile Virtual device testing using Testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

1. I wrote a simple code(using Javascript) to launch a site and to do some operations.
2. Using the Testcafe remote command, I am able to get the remote connection URL and QR code.

3.Using(copied) the remote URL, I wrote another Java program to run the remote URL in the virtual device using appium.

Can someone let me know, How can I automate the process to link step2 and step3?

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged as 'testcafe', but it is more related to automation of processes than to e2e testing with TestCafe.

TestCafe itself only gives you the remote link.

If you want to run your tests on mobile devices, you can check the [Browsers in Cloud Testing Services](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/browser-support.html#browsers-in-cloud-testing-services) article.